# I am not getting the row_num() properly in the DESC order

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not getting the `row_num()` properly in the `DESC` order

What I did:

- Find the total email sent by each user using the `COUNT()` function.
- Group records by from_user.
- Use the formula `ROW_NUMBER` to order records by total emails in descending order.
- Order users with the same number of emails alphabetically

My query:

```sql
SELECT from_user,
       COUNT(from_user) as email_sent,
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(from_user) DESC) as rnk
FROM google_gmail_emails
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY COUNT(from_user) DESC,
         from_user asc
```

Comment: Post the actual result (in table format) and what results you expected instead.

Comment: If `count(from_user)` is the same for a lot of `from_user` values then their ordering in a group is not predictable. Expand sorting expression, provide its uniqueness, use `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(from_user) DESC, from_user ASC) as rnk`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  select 
    from_user, 
    count(from_user) as email_sent,
    row_number() over (order by from_user asc) as alpha
    from google_gmail_emails 
    group by 1 order by count(from_user) desc, alpha;
```

this query will ordered records by total emails in descending and give the alphabetically sorted order row number in alpha column.